# Frequency of Signal of a point tracked in a video?

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, frequency, frequency-response, time-domain

I have used MATLAB to track a feature point (corner point) using Lucas-Kanade tracker and plotted its movement through each frame now I need to find its frequency content, how should I find it? (I have only taken $y$-axis movement of the corner point)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use Fourier transform by using FFT then find the magnitude of each frquency or simply find the power spectrum by functions like pwelch.